# How do you "OR" a two or more scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let say User has two scopes, "non_member" and "new_user". I'd like to OR them, including joins and order.

I tried to extract where clauses to construct an OR statement for two scopes. However, joins and orders are not included.

e.g.

```
non_member_where = User.non_member.where_values.reduce(:and)
new_user_where = User.new_user.where_values.reduce(:and)

@users = User.where("#{non_member_where} OR #{new_user_where}")
```

Non member scope needs to join a memberships table. If you the code above, that does not join as it only concerns with where.

Is there a better way how to "OR" two scopes? Something like

```
@users = User.non_member.or.new_user
```

That output something like this:

```
SELECT users.* FROM users LEFT JOINS memberships ON memberships.user_id = users.id
  WHERE((memberships.user_id IS NULL) OR (users.created_at < {{2 days ago}})
```

I'm using rails 3.2.12

Comment: I tried to do this recently and found that active record has poor support for OR. Might have changed recently. What Rails version are you using?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/33rwgw?i=2&p=1&q=author%3Aoelmekki&t%5B%5D=oelmekki

Comment: Im using rails 3.2.12

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord is built on top of a library called AReL.
You can drop down to the AReL table and get this functionality.

Alternatively you can use the Squeel gem which does the same thing but gives you a slightly higher level API.

Check out squeel: https://github.com/ernie/squeel